# Birkhoff orthogonal of a Banach space in its bidual

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space embedded in $X^{**}$ in the usual way.
We consider the set
$$
O_X := \{ x^{**}\in X^{**} : \|x^{**}-x\|\geq \|x\| \textrm{ for all }x\in X\}.
$$
I think this is the orthogonal set of the subspace $X$ in the sense of Birkhoff.
It is a closed cone in $X^{**}$, but not a subspace in general.

Suppose that $X$ is (isometrically) a dual space with unique predual $X_*$.
Hence $X^{**} = X \oplus X_*^\perp$ and, since the associated projection $X^{**}\to X$ has norm one, $X_*^\perp\subset O_X$.

QUESTION: Is is true in this special case that $X_*^\perp= O_X$?

Comment: I think you can find the answer in [this](http://books.google.ca/books?hl=en&lr=&id=dmw0HHs9ppMC&oi=fnd&pg=PA131&dq=%22G.+Godefroy%22&ots=VVMFiESVXA&sig=gB1BJyk-IcE0Yw9XhfxbjssDJ70#v=onepage&q=%22G.%20Godefroy%22&f=false) survey

Comment: @Norbert: I have a copy of that survey. I studied it some time ago, and I thought then that the answer to my question was obviously positive. However I have recently realized that I was mistaken, or cannot remember the argument. Could you be more precise in your observation?

Comment: I' just scrolled this survey few month ago that is why I thought it might containt the answer. Unfortunately I do not have full access, so I can't help you with exact reference.